# Seep mysql connections on horizon:work redis

Tags: mysql, queue, horizon

Laravel Version
9.52.4

PHP Version
8.2.4

Database Driver & Version
MySQL 8.0.31

Description
On horizon start, it start multiple processes (depends on number of queues), like
artisan horizon:work redis --name=name --supervisor=foo --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=queueName --sleep=3 --timeout=60 --tries=1 --rest=0

With every this process, it create mysql connection with command = 'sleep'. When we have for example, 2 workers and 20 queues, it will be create 40 sleep connections.

Have you encountered this problem?

Steps To Reproduce

- new Laravel project
- queue with horizon
- start horizon
- start job

I tried to manually close DB connection, with catch after/failing/exception events:

`Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {      DB::disconnect();  });`

but it only decreased ~50%.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please post your code responsible for Connect, Process, Close for review.  Likely the close is not working, leaving SLEEP process forever.